# Magento 2 Layered Navigation doesn't show search filter's values

Tags: layered-navigation, search, catalogsearch, magento-2.1.7

I have a store with 10 products simple , configurable and grouped. My category layered navigation is working fine with filterable attributes. but when I search it shows empty attributes.

I did the reindex , cache clean  also still same issue. need help about this issue. I'm using default layered navigation magento version 2.1.7

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

please check below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is that ok for you?

Comment: thanks , I did it but didn't show the options. I added attributes after product creation. but I have assigned the attributes to products. Color and size attributes are shown, category etc attributes are just attribute title.

Comment: based on issue attribute not showing, it is showing now right?

Comment: still have same issue.

Comment: have you checked with default theme?

Comment: yes I checked all the possibilities, I have doubt I used elastic search then disable it.

Comment: have you did reindex after change search engine

Comment: Yes, reindex cache clean. deploy . all the things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72755/discussion-between-sunil-patel-and-lasantha).